# Node.js not downloading full website

Tags: node.js

I expext this code to download the website and then execute the callback function when it finished downloading.

```
var request = require("request");

var options = {
  uri: "http://www.hellointernet.fm/podcast?format=rss",
  headers: {
    'User-Agent': 'request'
  }
};

request(options, function(error, response, body) {
  console.log(body);
});
```

But it doesn't download the full website when executing the callback. I tried it with other URLs and it worked.

How can I wait until the full page is downloaded?

Comment: Well, there's definitely something up with this server.  There's nothing wrong with your code.  If you run a packet sniffer on it, you can see that the server actually stops sending data prematurely.  Now the question is why.

Comment: Ah, this server isn't handling `connection: close` correctly.

Comment: It does seem to work from the command line `curl -A "request" http://www.hellointernet.fm/podcast?format=rss`

Comment: @doublesharp User-Agent string isn't an issue here.  I'll post an explanation in a second, just need to modify the code.

Comment: @Brad I didn't want to assume since it's set in the options in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you're dealing with a badly behaved server.  Your code is fine.

On the wire, your application writes this HTTP request:

```
GET /podcast?format=rss HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: request
host: www.hellointernet.fm
Connection: close
```

The server then responds with data that varies in length with each request, somewhere between 70KB and the full 360,872 bytes we're expecting.  The connection is getting closed before the server's buffer is fully sent.  Broken server, not much you can do about that.

However, if you instead tell the server that you intend to use HTTP/1.1 keep-alive, it works.

```
GET /podcast?format=rss HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: request
host: www.hellointernet.fm
Connection: keep-alive
```

The reason is that the server isn't prematurely closing the connection.  Basically, you're hacking around the server's bug.

To implement this in your code, add this near the top:

```
var http = require('http');
```

Then, in your request options:

```
agent: http.Agent({keepAlive: true})
```

Basically, this tells the request module to use an HTTP agent (which is what enables keep-alive in Node.js applications).  With the agent, the HTTP client can then make an HTTP request with keep-alive, which hacks around the server problem.

I recommend contacting whomever runs hellointernet.fm and tell them that their server is badly broken.  This is likely breaking all sorts of clients.

Comment: @PeterMaskulio No problem.  If you want to debug this stuff yourself in the future, I recommend getting cozy with Wireshark and Fiddler.  I use Fiddler a lot because it's really good at detecting HTTP protocol violations, many of which aren't detectable in the browser-based HTTP request tools.